# How to add CSS to iframe content only using the head of HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, inline

I hope someone can help me with this because I don't know any solution for this... I have a Blog with Google's Blogger plattform, so I only can write my CSS styles inline - no extra files.

My question: Blogger is using an iframe for the comment section and I want to optimize it for mobile devices. Is there ANY way to add some CSS to the iframe content only using the head of the HTML / XML page? Maybe with some Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `<style>`?

```
<style> /* put your code here */ </style>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for the iframe content :/ This only works for the iframe box (width / height etc.) but I need to style the content of the iframe.

Comment: Well, if css is loaded with the page you can change any element of the page. Sometimes you have to use !important to replace some elements.
Give a look https://www.thoughtco.com/iframes-and-css-3468669
And if you need more help, edit your question and post your code

Answer (score 0):

You will need to put your css code in the page the iframe shows.
Due to security you cant interact with a page inside an iframe by javascript, so you have to have all the code in there. If you cant write code in it than I domt think it is possible, but if you can at least add a script in you can possibly add the element containing the stylesheet.